# Blend Project is created empty in Blend 5 (Windows 8 Consumer Preview)

Tags: c#, xaml, expression-blend, windows-8, winrt-xaml

I am trying to create a metro style project using Blend (in Windows 8 consumer preview).

I launch Blend, select "New Project" and selected C# (Metro style App).

No matter which project i select, the project is created empty:

[image]

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you have the correct Blend version? My current used on CP is 5.0.30129.0. You say "C# (Metro Style App)" my current Blend offers "XAML (Windows Metro Style)" - this might be an indication of the older version.

Alternatively the installation of your Blend is broken. So probably re-install might help.

However I never create new projects in Blend. **I create them always in Visual Studio and only open the .sln file in Blend afterwards.** I suggest you try that approach as the very first step.

Just to illustrate... in my case the create dialog looks like this:

[image: Blend - New Project]

And after OK this is my Solution Explorer:

[image: Blend - New Project]

Comment: Are you doing this on Win8? did u have to manually adjust any environment variables? ( VisualStudioVersion) or the CSharp.common targets file?

Comment: Yes, all done on Win 8. And no - I did not have to adjust any env variables - all worked out of the box. Have you tried to create your project in Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes, it didn't work out as well. After playing around with that env variable it seems to work fine. Thanks.